# How to catch DNSLookupFailedError in Python on GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, error-handling, dns, urlfetch

I test URLs provided by people with urlfetch to catch wrong links.

```
result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
```

When I provide an URL such as «http://qwerty.uiop» the log says there was «DNSLookupFailedError», but this code wouldn't catch it:

```
except urlfetch.DNSLookupFailedError:
self.error(400)
self.response.out.write(
  'Sorry, there was a problem with URL "' + url + '"')
```

I also tried "except urlfetch.Error:" and "except urlfetch.DownloadError:"

What am I doing wrong, and is there another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

In the local developer environment and in production I actually see a different exception: `DownloadError`. Catching that worked fine for me.

```
try:
  result = urlfetch.fetch('http://qwerty.uiop')
except urlfetch.DownloadError:
  self.response.write('Oops!')
```

Comment: I can't reproduce what you get since I don't have a local development environment — I'm doing development on an iPad. But that didn't fix it in production environment. It still says: raise DNSLookupFailedError('DNS lookup failed for URL: ' + url)
DNSLookupFailedError: DNS lookup failed for URL: http://thdienr.rurhf

Comment: Is there a different way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? I'm only three days with python and GAE, so I get lost in these little things often.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say you have no local development environment. The App Engine SDK ships with a local development environment, dev_appserver.py (or the Mac launcher). Are you using an online class to do development? If so, it's possible their environment is adding additional behavior on top of the regular production environment.

Comment: I SSH from an iPad to an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance where I only "./appcfg.py update myapp". Then I test my code directly on GAE — which I called the production environment above which might have been wrong of me to do. So there is no local environment whatsoeverever. Sorry for not making myself clear enough.

Comment: It's still the same production environment I'm using (Google's servers). What version of the SDK are you using?